# Access to CUDA library functions inside specialized instantiations of __device__ function templates

Tags: cuda, template-specialization

I have the following template `__device__` function in CUDA:

```
template<typename T>
__device__ void MyatomicAdd(T *address, T val){
atomicAdd(address , val);
}
```

that compiles and runs just fine if instantiated with T as a float, i.e.

```
__global__ void myKernel(float *a, float b){
MyatomicAdd<float>(a,b);
}
```

will run without a problem.

I wanted to specialize this function, as there is no `atomicAdd()` for doubles, so I can hand code an implementation in double precision. Ignoring the double precision specialization for now, the single precision specialization and template look like this:

```
template<typename T>
__device__ void MyatomicAdd(T *address, T val){
};


template<>
__device__ void MyatomicAdd<float>(float *address, float val){
atomicAdd(address , val);
}
```

Now the compiler complains that atomicAdd() is undefined in my specialization, the same applies when I try to use any CUDA functions like __syncthreads() within the specialization. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to compile the specialisation with the wrong compiler. Are you really using nvcc, and does the file being compiled have a .cu extension?

Comment: The first unspecialized example and 2nd specialized example both exist in the same file. I just commented out the first example after I wrote the second. It seems to be a specific problem with specialization.

Comment: The thing is that I can take the code you posted, stick it in a file with a kernel, compile it with nvcc and there are no errors. So there is something different that you are neglecting to tell us..

Comment: I'll try placing it in a different file. There are a few other kernels and device functions in the same cu file so maybe there's some interference somewhere.

Comment: It does compile in a different cu file with another kernel, the search continues..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a linking problem with some OpenGL code developed by a colleague. Forcing the specializations to be inline fixed the problem, although obviously not the root cause. Still, it'll do for now until I can be be bothered to dig through the other guy's code.